# Fast way to fill a python list to target length

Tags: python

I want to fill one of my list to the same length with the others, so they can be used in later pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list1,list2,list3],columns= column_name_list)
```

for example, my column_name_list is with length 5
but if list1,list2,list3 is only with length 3, eg:

```
list1= ['a','b','c']
```

Before parsing it to dataframe, is there any fast way(like single line) to fill the list1 to target length 5?
What I expect is list1 to be

```
['a','b','c','empty_or_the_string_I_defined_or_from_target_list','empty_or_the_string_I_defined_or_from_target_list']
```

I want to fill the rest with blank or specific string or even the same element as target column name list

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest might be:

```
  list1 + ['empty_or_the_string_I_defined_or_from_target_list'] * (target_length - len(list1))
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks,this is good.Another possible may use the same element in target list. Is it a way to copy the same position element from target_list?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What do you mean by "copy the same position element from target_list"? You can just use `[target_list[index]]*(target_len - len(list1))`, if that's what you mean. Multiplying a list by an integer just creates a list containing that many copies of the original list. It does not matter what the list contains.

Answer (score 3):

One way using `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list2 = ["aa", "bb"]
list3 = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]
columns = ['col0', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

padded = list(zip_longest(columns, list1, list2, list3, fillvalue="Fillme"))
print(padded)
```

Output:

```
[('col0', 'a', 'aa', 'aaa'),
 ('col1', 'b', 'bb', 'bbb'),
 ('col2', 'c', 'Fillme', 'ccc'),
 ('col3', 'Fillme', 'Fillme', 'ddd'),
 ('col4', 'Fillme', 'Fillme', 'Fillme')]
```

You can then use `pandas.DataFrame.set_index` with `T` to make a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(padded).set_index(0).T
print(df)
```

Output:

```
0 col0 col1    col2    col3    col4
1    a    b       c  Fillme  Fillme
2   aa   bb  Fillme  Fillme  Fillme
3  aaa  bbb     ccc     ddd  Fillme
```